# If I have a spring mvc rest controller returning byte[], how would I download to my android app using volley?

Tags: spring-mvc, android-volley, networkimageview

I need to implement a list view containing a thumbnail, and this thumbnail is loaded using volley networkimageview. How would I implement this if my controller looks like this:

@RequestMapping (value="/rest/getphoto/", produces=MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody byte [] get Image (@RequestParam ("imageId"));

I've found many examples regarding the usage of volley but they are not helping me. Besides, I am using secure connection. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I'm including controller code in my spring mvc project and the portion of code in my android client requesting an image.

*** Spring MVC ***

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/singlephoto/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody byte[] base64ImageForAndroid(@RequestParam("photoId") String photoIdParam, HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        String pathToLoad = "/path/default.png";
        //HashMap<String, String> retVal = new HashMap<String, String>();
        byte[] retVal;

        try
        {
            long photoId = Long.parseLong(photoIdParam);
            Photo photo = photoManager.getSinglePhoto(photoId);

            if (photo != null)
                pathToLoad = photo.getPath();
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                File file = new File(pathToLoad);
                retVal = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                retVal = null;
            }
        }

        return retVal;
```

*** Android Client Requesting with volley ***

```
Bitmap thumb = imageCache.get(item.getThumbnailUrl() + "thumb");
        if (thumb == null)
        {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            HttpBasicAuthentication auth = new HttpBasicAuthentication(this.username, this.password);
            headers.setAuthorization(auth);
            headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));

            Listener<byte[]> imageLoadedListener = new Response.Listener<byte[]>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(byte[] photoByteArray) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = EfficientImageLoading.decodeBitmapFromByteArray(photoByteArray, viewHolder.thumbnail.getWidth(), viewHolder.thumbnail.getHeight());

                    viewHolder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    imageCache.put(item.getThumbnailUrl() + "thumb", bitmap);

                    //Cache full size and recycle
                    Bitmap fullBmp = EfficientImageLoading.decodeImageFromByteFullSize(photoByteArray);
                    imageCache.put(item.getThumbnailUrl(), fullBmp);
                }
            };

            ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    viewHolder.thumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                }
            };

            this.singleInstance.addToRequestQueue(new CustomImageRequest(Request.Method.GET, item.getThumbnailUrl(), errorListener, headers, imageLoadedListener));
}
```

Application server logs show:

GET /app//photo/rest/singlephoto/?photoId=7 HTTP/1.1" 406 1067

That is 406-- forbidden or something like that. Also android's LogCat shows an error like the following: BasicNetwork.PerformRequest: Unexpected response code 406 for https://domain/app/singlephoto?photoId=7

Is there something wrong with my controller or my client or both?

Comment: I've never heard of volley before, but I can use google and find documentation. Here's the documentation explaining how to request for images: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html#request-image. Use it with `https://your.host/rest/getphoto?imageId=42` as the URL to get the image identified with 42

Comment: Thanks for your reply @JB Nizet. As I said I've seen many examples but they're not really helpful. For example, I need to set authorization header before requesting the image over SSL. Once I set up headers, I'd like to know how to handle the response, since the rest controller isn't returning json.

Comment: How to handle the response is explained in the link I posted. Read it. And if your question is "how to add a header to a volley request?", then why don't you say a single word about that in your question? ImageRequest has a getHeader() method returning a Map of headers. I guess you can add your header to that map.

Comment: Because I would like to see the whole picture. As you can see, there are many parts involved in downloading the image to my application, therefore I would like to see if someone around here can provide a link that can lead me to a correct solution. I appreciate your suggestions but I would like to see working examples.

Comment: StackOverflow is not for finding working examples. It's for asking concrete questions.

Comment: My question is concrete, your answer quite vague though

Comment: It's not an answer, it's a comment. I told you to read the documentation showing a concrete example of what you want to do, and you didn't even click the link. Then you told that the problem was with headers, and I told you how to add one. Then you changed your question again, and told that you wanted to find a link with a correct solution. I already gave you one, but you didn't care. And anyway, if what you're looking is a link, then use Google. Questions asking for links, tutorials or other offline resources are off-topic.

Comment: The thing is that I don't come asking questions without doing some research first. I have seen this documentation earlier, but I cannot get this to work. That's why I would like to see if someone can provide a link I've missed, but android docs is one of the things that appear on the first page of results. I was hoping to find an answer saying something like check this guy's blog about  volley implementing or a sample application at git.. something like that because I cannot manage to put all the pieces together.

Comment: Then post the code you have tried, and tell us precisely how it doesn't work, including all the complete and exact error messages you get, instead of asking for a link showing a correct solution.

Comment: OK I'll post the code after updating my question.

Comment: @JBNizet I updated my question, could you take a look at it?

Comment: 406 is not " forbidden or something like that". Use google and read http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html. 406 means "not acceptable". You're telling the server that you only accept responses with content-type APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM. And the server produces image/png.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet you're absolutely right. You have taught me a lot in a single day, if I worked with you, I'd learn so much. It is now working, and I confused 406 with 403. My mistake. Thanks again and have a wonderful programming day.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to have helped.